# Send Image with android to openCV server with C++ and C++ Rest SDK

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv

First: Sorry for my English which is not very good.

I'm doing a project and need help because I'm new in web services and C++ Rest SDk.
I have an android interface and with this I capture a photo and in the other hand I have a C++ code with OpenCV libraries and I need to use this code to receive the image captured with the phone.

I searched over the web and I found a C++Rest SDk to do a web service but I don't know exactly what is it that I need.

I need a server application?

What is the source code in C++ to wait a request from the mobile phone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you need to use the C++ file to process the image picked up by the android?

Instead of using a web service to pass the image to the C++ code, you could look into using the android NDK (Native Development Kit), that way you can just pass the image straight to the C++ code all within one application without having to mess around with sending it over the web?

https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

^ Link to the NDK download and information ^

Apologies if I have misunderstood and you need the image processing running on a separate machine.

If this is the case try looking into the EMGU wrapper which will allow you to make your code in C# which has really handy web functionality.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Aphire, but if I undertstod correctly the ndk is to use C++ source in a native android aplication no?

I need processing image in a other server becouse this processing is very costly for the movile phone and after de processing the server return the same imatge with rectangles indicating where is the text.

I don't know if I'm explain correctly, you understand me?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes I understand, I would suggest that you look into using the EMGU wrapper available to convert your image processing code to C# and use all their nice web functionality.